# How to catch error in ChangeNotifier after widget deactivated?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have code in `Model` for execution. I provide `Model` with `Provider`. But if `Model` is dispose before finish execution I get error:

> E/flutter (26180): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)]
>   Unhandled Exception: A Model was used after being disposed. E/flutter
>   (26180): Once you have called dispose() on a Model, it can no longer
>   be used.

For example `Model` is dispose if user press back button so `Navigator.pop()`. This because `Model` is only scope to this Widget.

But that mean I cannot catch error in `Model`?

My code:

```
class Model extends ChangeNotifier {

  bool error = false;

  func() {

    try {

    await execute();
    error = false

    } catch {
    error = true;
    print(e.toString());
    }

  }

}



class ExampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      builder: (context) => Model(),
child: Consumer<Model>(builder: (context, model, _) {
return FloatingActionButton(
  child: model.error ? Icon(Icons.error) : Icon(Icons.check),
  onPressed: () {
    model.func();
  }
);

    …
```

How I can catch error in Model after dispose?

Comment: You posted this question already yesterday and deleted it with my answer. How were you able to delete it, even though I provided an aswer?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I post bad question before. This more specific. You answer was wrong. Even if check `mounted?` with Stateful Widget still get error that widget is `deactivated`. I hope with more code everyone can see more clear why I can not catch error and print to console

Answer (score 9):

I just had the same problem.

The error occurs because you use one of the `ChangeNotifier` methods, usually `notifyListeners()` (which I'm assuming you're calling, but left out of the pasted code) after `dispose()` has been called. By the way, it's an assert error, so only in debug builds.

To get rid of the error, you could check if the object has been disposed before calling `notifyListeners()` with your own flag:

```
class Model extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool error = false;
  bool isDisposed = false;

  func() {
    try {
      await execute();
      error = false
    } catch {
      error = true;
      print(e.toString());
    }

    if (!isDisposed) {
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    isDisposed = true;
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure my problem was exactly the same, but I had some unused "notifiyListeners" in my code and caused my to get this error...

Removing solved it!!!